# Boost Asio tcp::iostream construction raise an Access Violation Exception on every second use

Tags: sockets, visual-c++, boost, iostream, asio

I am trying to use the implementation of `std::iostream` provided by `boost::asio` on top of `boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket`. My code replicate almost line to line the example that is [published in Boost Asio's documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/iostreams/daytime_server.cpp):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

#include <boost/asio.hpp>

int main()
{
    using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
    try
    {
        boost::asio::io_service io_service;
        tcp::endpoint endpoint(tcp::v4(), 8000);
        tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_service, endpoint);

        for (;;)
        {
            tcp::iostream stream;  // <-- The exception is triggered on this line, on the second loop iteration.
            boost::system::error_code error_code;
            acceptor.accept(*stream.rdbuf(), error_code);
            std::cout << stream.rdbuf() << std::flush;
        }
    }
    catch (std::exception& exception)
    {
        std::cerr << exception.what() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The only difference is the use I make of the resulting `tcp::iostream`: I forward everything I receive to the standard output.

When I compile this code with VisualStudio2019/toolset v142 and Boost from the NuGet [boost-vc142](https://www.nuget.org/packages/boost-vc142/), I get an Access Violation Exception **only in the second iteration in the `for` loop**, in the function

```
template <typename Service>
Service& service_registry::use_service(io_context& owner)
{
  execution_context::service::key key;
  init_key<Service>(key, 0);
  factory_type factory = &service_registry::create<Service, io_context>;
  return *static_cast<Service*>(do_use_service(key, factory, &owner));
} // <-- The debugger show the exception was raised on this line
```

in `asio/detail/impl/service_registry.hpp`. So the first iteration everything goes as planned, the connection is accepted, the data shows up on the standard output, and as soon as the `stream` is instanciated on the stack for the second time, the exception pops.

I don't have a high confidence in the accuracy of this location of the exception reported by the debugger. For some reason, the stack seams to be messed up and show only one frame.

If the declaration of `stream` is moved out of the loop, no exception is raised any more but then I need to `stream.close()` at the end of the loop, or nothing shows up on the standard output except the data from the first client's connection.

Basically, as soon as I try to instanciate more than one `boost::asio::tcp::iostream` (not necessarily at the same time), the exception is raised.

I tried the exact same code under linux (Arch linux, latest version of g++, same version of Boost) and everything works perfectly.

I could work around this issue by not using `iostream`s, but my idea is to feed the data received on the tcp socket to a parser which only accept implementations of `std::iostream`, hence I would still need to wrap asio's tcp socket in an homebrewed (and mediocre) implementation of `std::iostream`.

Does anybody have an idea on what's wrong with this setup, if I missed a crucial `#define` somewhere or anything?

## Update:

Subsequent investigation show that the only situation where the access violation happens is when the executable is run from within Visual Studio (typ. from the menu Debug -> Start Debugging).

The build process seems to have no effect (calling directly `cl.exe`, using `MSBuild`, using `devenv.exe`).

Moreover, if the executable is run from a command prompt, and only then the debugger is attached, no access violation happens.

At this point, the issue is most likely not linked to the code itself.

Comment: Is the real code `tcp::socket;`? What does that do?

Comment: Yes, `tcp::socket;` is a valid statement, but it does nothing (it's a type that resolve to `boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp>`). I redacted the question to remove it for clarity.

Comment: I never doubted it was a valid statement. I just managed to test even on windows, and posted my findings. [I can confirm the spurious line didn't have an effect even so.]

Answer (score 1):

Okay, it was exceedingly painful to test this on windows.

Of course I first tried on Linux (clang/gcc) and MingW 8.1 on windows.

Then I bit the bullet and jumped the hoops to get MSVC in command line with boost packages¹.

I cheated by manually copying the .lib/.dll for boost_{system,date_time,regex} into the working directory so the command line stayed "wieldy":

```
C:\work>C:\Users\sghee\Downloads\nuget.exe install boost_system-vc142
C:\work>C:\Users\sghee\Downloads\nuget.exe install boost_date_time-vc142
C:\work>C:\Users\sghee\Downloads\nuget.exe install boost_regex-vc142
```

(Be sure to get some coffee during *those*)

```
C:\work\> cl /EHsc test.cpp /I .\boost.1.72.0.0\lib\native\include /link
```

Now I can run test.exe

```
C:\work\> test.exe
```

And it listens fine, accepts connections (sequentially, not simultaneously). If you connect a second client while the first is still connected, it will be queued and be accepted only after the first disconnects. That's fine, because it's what you expect with the synchronous `accept` and loop.

I used Ncat.exe (from Nmap) to connect:

```
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Nmap>.\ncat.exe localhost 8000
```

> Quirk: The buffering was fine with the MSVC cl.exe build (linewise) as opposed to MingW behaviour, even though MingW also uses ws2_32.dll. #trivia

I know this doesn't "help", but maybe you can compare notes and see what is different with your system.

### Video Of Test

[image]

---

¹ (that's a tough job without VS and also I - obviously - ran out of space, because 50GiB for a VM can't be enough right)

Comment: Added a gif of the tests in my Win10 VM

Comment: Ok, so we are getting into weird territory here. I could replicate your steps with the same result: no access violation. But in fact, the **only** way I get the access violation is when I run the executable **from within** Visual Studio with debugger attached. If I run it externally and **only then** attach the debugger, there is no access violation. So the issue is most likely related to VS than anything else.